# Geohash Roll up Graph (level 5) from (level7) with Cypher?

Tags: cypher, cypher-3.1

I am trying to create a geohash graph with level 5 of zoom from an existing one with level 7.
i tried this code :

```
 FROM GRAPH mergedGraph
 MATCH (from)-[via]->(to)
 CASE WHEN substring(from.geohash,0,5)=substring(to.geohash,0,5)
 THEN
 CONSTRUCT
 CREATE (h:HashNode{geohash:substring(from.geohash,0,5)})-[COPY OF via]->(h)
 ELSE
 CONSTRUCT create (:HashNode{geohash:substring(from.geohash,0,5)})-[COPY OF via]->(:HashNode{geohash:substring(to.geohash,0,5)})
 END
 RETURN GRAPH
```

however it dosen't seem true in cypher ,i get an exception :

```
Caused by: org.opencypher.v9_0.util.SyntaxException: Invalid input 'S': expected 'l/L' (line 4, column 4 (offset: 57))
```

In english words i want  : 
if the  start node and the end node share the same geohash substring then create one node with the relationship that point back to it:

[image: intra relationship]

else 
create two nodes :

[image: inter relationship]

**NB**: *The project i am  working at is CYPHER FOR APACHE SPARK*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this steps:

1) Create a graph with Level 5 from the existing one :

```
//Creation Geohash Graph with level 5 from the initial graph (level 7)
   val Level5 = session.cypher("""
                      | FROM GRAPH mergeGraph
                      | MATCH (from)-[via]->(to)
                      | CONSTRUCT
                      |  CREATE (:HashNode{geohash:substring(from.geohash,0,5)})-[COPY OF via]->(:HashNode{geohash:substring(to.geohash,0,5)})
                      | RETURN GRAPH
                      """.stripMargin).graph
```

2) Copy distant nodes from the previous graph :

```
session.cypher ("""
 | CATALOG CREATE GRAPH nodes2 {
 | FROM GRAPH session.Level5
 | MATCH (n)
 | WITH DISTINCT n.geohash AS geohash
 |CONSTRUCT
 | CREATE (h:HashNode{geohash:geohash})
 |RETURN GRAPH
  }""".stripMargin)
```

finally:

3) Create the distant level5 graph by copying relationships from the first one and affecting them to the distant nodes

```
val level5= session.cypher("""
                               FROM GRAPH Level5
                              |  MATCH (from)-[via]->(to)
                              |  FROM GRAPH nodes2
                              |  MATCH (n), (m)
                              |  WHERE from.geohash=n.geohash AND to.geohash = m.geohash
                               construct
                              |    CREATE (n)-[COPY OF via]->(m)
                              |  RETURN GRAPH
                           """.stripMargin).graph
```

[image: Geohash Level 5]